# OpenGL Texture corruption

Tags: opengl

i am rendering simple pixel buffer in OpenGL. First, i create a quad, then i create a texture. It works correctly if there is no changes in buffer. When i change my buffer and add new buffer into texture by `glTexSubImage2D` or `glTexImage2D` my texture's top section corrupts like image.

[image: Corrupted image]

I create my buffer like this.

```
int length = console->width * console->height * 3;
GLubyte buf[length];

for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
    buf[i] = 0;
    buf[i + 1] = 0;
    buf[i + 2] = 0;
}

console->buffer = buf;
```

I create texture like this.

```
glGenTextures(1, &console->textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, console->textureID);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, console->width, console->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, console->buffer);
tpUseShader(console); // -> calls glUseShader(console->programID);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(console->programID, "texture"), 0);
```

I update texture like this.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, console->textureID);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, console->width, console->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, console->buffer);
```

For testing i change my buffer like this in render function

```
if(console->buffer[6] == 255) {
    console->buffer[6] = 0; // 6 is second pixel's red value.
    console->buffer[10] = 255; // 10 is third pixel's green value
} else {
    console->buffer[6] = 255;
    console->buffer[10] = 0;
}
```

Then i call tpUseShader and render my quad.

How can i fix this problem?

I changed my console size to 10x10 and run again this time i got same results but, in image you can see from bottom left 3rd pixel is dark blue. When i print `printf("3rd pixel: %d- %d - %d\n", console->buffer[12], console->buffer[13], console->buffer[14]);`. value i got red: 0 green: 0 blue: 0 values. That means my buffer is normal.

[image: 10x10 corrupt image]

Comment: Not enough code to see where it fails. Seems like your `console->buffer` is ill formed for the second update. Different method for the first one?

Comment: I am just updating like `console->buffer[6] = 255; //6 is red` in my render function for testing.

Comment: Why do you use `int` for your buffer but `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for the texture?

Comment: I used `GLubyte` when creating buffer, and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` when creating texture.

Comment: If `buf` gets out of scope the entire data is garbage, be careful with that.  How do you render it?

Comment: I am setting `buf` before getting out of scope to `console->buffer`. I am rendering with `glBindVertexArray(console->quadVao);
  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);`

Comment: `buf` has to stay in scope for the whole duration of the application or the storage will be no longer valid.

Comment: Try setting internal format to GL_RGB8: `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, console->width, console->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, console->buffer);`

Comment: First, have you called `glGetError` to verify all the OpenGL calls are succeeding?  Next, do you call `glActiveTexture` at all, or with a texture unit other than `GL_TEXTURE0`, since you hard code zero to _texture_ (assuming that's bound to your sampler in the shader).

Comment: When i call `glGetError` in `switch/case`, i am not getting `GL_NO_ERROR` also, i am not getting any error. `default` case is running. When i change `glActiveTexture` to anything except `GL_TEXTURE0` i got nothing rendered on my screen. Only `GL_TEXTURE0` renders, and that is corrupted. I changed internal format to `GL_RGB8` and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. As pleluron said in comments of question. I changed `buf` in to `console->buffer`, and it worked!. Now my buffer initialization code is like this:

```
console->buffer = malloc(sizeof(GLubyte) * length);

for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
    console->buffer[i] = 0;
    console->buffer[i + 1] = 0;
    console->buffer[i + 2] = 0;
}
```